# Checking for possible exceptions vs. wrapping code in try catch

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, try-catch, throw

I'm checking for invalid conditions in my method:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    int result;
    if (DeviceSettings == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Not initialized");
    if (!Serial.IsNotEmpty())
        throw new Exception("The serial number is empty.");
    if (!int.TryParse(Serial, out result))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Serial);

    //do stuff
}
```

The code looks awkward to me. Is there a more **standard approach** to implementing  logic that verifies that there are no **invalid conditions** ?

Comment: `if (!int.TryParse(Serial, out result))` what's up with this line..? where do you declare `result`? also if certain things like `DeviceSettings` is null is this something that the user would be in control of in regards to setting..? if so why not show or display a message..?

Comment: thank you, i've declared result. no this is not something the user is in control of

Answer (score 1):

I like to restrict throwing exceptions to truly "exceptional" situations.  For something like you have above, I would have a "response" type of data structure returned from DoStuff() instead of a void, that could contain a list of validation errors.

```
class Response()
{
     public List<string> errors {get;set;}
}
public Response DoStuff()
{
    var response = new Response();
    int result;
    if (DeviceSettings == null)
        response.errors.Add("Not Initialized");
    if (!Serial.IsNotEmpty())
        response.errors.Add("The serial number is empty.");
    if (!int.TryParse(Serial, out result))
        response.errors.Add("Argument out of range");
    // check your response errors, return if necessary
    //do stuff
    return response;
}
```

This way, in the case of data validation errors, you get all possible errors instead of just the first one.